# Javascript files not working when loaded into footer

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Ok so I am working on a website that has its own custom plugin. I wanted to get all the js files for this plugin to load into the footer as it was slowing the website down. I know how to get them to load into the footer but when I do this the js files seem to not be working anymore, even though I can see them in the footer when I inspect the page. Anybody know what could be causing this?

```
function enqueue_stairbuilder_js()
{

wp_register_script('simplemodal', plugins_url('js/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), "1.4.4", true);
wp_register_script('paper', plugins_url('js/paper.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ),"1.0.1", true);
wp_register_script('prices', plugins_url('js/prices.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), "", true);
wp_register_script('popup', plugins_url('js/popup.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), "1.0.3", true);
wp_register_script('printelement', plugins_url('js/printElement.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), "1.0.3", true);
wp_register_script('stairbuilder', plugins_url('js/stairbuilder.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ),"1.0.3", true);        
wp_register_script('drawing', plugins_url('js/drawing.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ),"1.0.3", true);
wp_register_script('deserialise', plugins_url('js/deserialise.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ),"1.0.3", true);

wp_enqueue_script('simplemodal');
wp_enqueue_script('paper');
wp_enqueue_script('prices');
wp_enqueue_script('popup');
wp_enqueue_script('printelement');
wp_enqueue_script('stairbuilder');
wp_enqueue_script('drawing');
wp_enqueue_script('deserialise');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stairbuilder_js' );
```

here's the contents of my functions file incase I have done something wrong here which is causing this.

```
<?php


    //custom gallery image size, cropped
    add_image_size( 'gallery-thumb', 720, 720, true );

    //removing toolbar on front end
    function remove_toolbar(){
        if ( is_blog_admin() ) {
            return true;
        }
        remove_action( 'wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb' );
        return false;
    }
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'remove_toolbar' );

    //replacing default jQuery with new version
    function update_jQuery(){
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js', '3.2.1');
    } 
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'update_jQuery');

    //MY SCRIPTS
    function my_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'));
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script');

    //BOOTSTRAP
    function bootstrap(){
        wp_register_script('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.6', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js');
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', '3.3.7',true); 
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap');

    function my_styles(){
        wp_enqueue_style('theme_styles', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/my_styles.css', true);
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles');

    //magnific img popup
    function magnific_popup(){
        wp_register_script('magnific_js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/magnific_popup.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
        wp_enqueue_style('magnific_css', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/magnific_popup.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('magnific_js');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'magnific_popup');

    /*NAV MENUS*/
    function register_my_menus() {
        register_nav_menus(array(
            'head_nav' => __( 'Primary' ),
            'foot_nav' => __( 'Secondary' ),
            'side_bar_menu' => __( 'side_bar' )
        ) );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

    //enqueuing default style sheet
    wp_enqueue_style('default_style', get_stylesheet_uri());

    require get_template_directory() . '/woo_hooks.php';
?>
```

Comment: If browser still load your js files but not working, try to find out what happened in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this example:

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'xxx', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xxx/2.2.0/xxx.js', array('jquery'), 3.3, true); 
   wp_enqueue_script( 'xxy', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xxy/2.2.0/xxy.js', array('jquery'), 3.3, true); 

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your cache. [The codex also recommends](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) If you are using the plugins_url() function in a file that is nested inside a subdirectory of your plugin directory, you should use PHP's dirname() function:

So try this.

```
function enqueue_stairbuilder_js()
{
    wp_register_script('simplemodal', plugins_url('js/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array( 'jquery' ), "1.4.4", true);
    wp_register_script('paper', plugins_url('js/paper.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array( 'jquery' ),"1.0.1", true);
    wp_register_script('prices', plugins_url('js/prices.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array( 'jquery' ), "", true);
    wp_register_script('popup', plugins_url('js/popup.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array( 'jquery' ), "1.0.3", true);
    wp_register_script('printelement', plugins_url('js/printElement.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array( 'jquery' ), "1.0.3", true);
    wp_register_script('stairbuilder', plugins_url('js/stairbuilder.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array( 'jquery' ),"1.0.3", true);        
    wp_register_script('drawing', plugins_url('js/drawing.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array( 'jquery' ),"1.0.3", true);
    wp_register_script('deserialise', plugins_url('js/deserialise.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array( 'jquery' ),"1.0.3", true);

    wp_enqueue_script('simplemodal');
    wp_enqueue_script('paper');
    wp_enqueue_script('prices');
    wp_enqueue_script('popup');
    wp_enqueue_script('printelement');
    wp_enqueue_script('stairbuilder');
    wp_enqueue_script('drawing');
    wp_enqueue_script('deserialise');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stairbuilder_js' );
```